# C# - Public string only stores last value outside of collection

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am using HtmlAgilityPack to find all items, colours and links to products on a website. I want to be able to find an item on the website by typing in the name and colour inside my application.

So far what I have working is:
The application finds items using only the item name and returns the last thing on the website with that name. There are multiple products with the same name but each have a different colour.

The problem comes in when including colour because it's in a different XPath so it's stored in a different collection.

Here is my code:

```
HtmlNodeCollection collection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class,'inner-article')]//h1//a");
HtmlNodeCollection collection2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class,'inner-article')]//p//a");


foreach (var node2 in collection2)
{
string coloursv = node2.InnerHtml.ToString();
strColour = coloursv;

//txtLog.Text += Environment.NewLine + (DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")) + str; - This code returns all colours (If code is ran outside of collection then only last colour in string is returned.

}

foreach (var node in collection)
{
string href = node.Attributes["href"].Value;
var itemname = node.InnerHtml.ToString();

if (itemname.Contains(txtKeyword.Text))
{
txtLog.Text = (DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")) + " - Item Found: " + href + " " + itemname + " " + strColour; //Successfully returns item name, colour and link but always gives last availible on website
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are continually setting the `Text` property of a textbox within a loop (so each item will continually overwrite the previous):

```
foreach (var node in collection)
{
    // Omitted for brevity

    // This will continually overwrite the contents of your Text property
    txtLog.Text = ...;
}
```

If you want to store multiple items, you'll either need to store the results in some type of a collection object (such as a ListBox, etc.) or by simply concatenating your values into the textbox:

```
foreach (var node in collection)
{
    // Omitted for brevity
    var stringToAdd = ...;
    txtLog.Text += stringToAdd + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

You can also accomplish this by using the `StringBuilder` class to be a bit more efficient:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var node in collection)
{
    // Omitted for brevity
    var stringToAdd = ...;
    // Append this item to the results
    sb.AppendLine(stringToAdd);   
}

// Store the results
txtLog.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks that works but the problem is that it just returns everything. For some reason it doesn't let me look for a match and return the matching item that has the same name and colour.